# sscanf accepts too may spaces

Tags: c, scanf

Is there a way to force sscanf to NOT allow extra whitespace.

Following code accepts `"N_ 234"`, even though it should only accept `"N_234"`:

```
int r;
unsigned b;
r = sscanf("N_ 234", "N_%u", &b); /* Returns 1 */
```

Tested with IAR compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be my code helpful to you:

```
# define SIZE 100
int main(){
    int r;
    unsigned b = 0u;
    char s[SIZE] = {0};
    sscanf("N_234", "%[N_0-9]", s);
    r = sscanf(s,"N_%u",&b);
    printf("%u\n",b);

}
```

`printf("%u\n",b);` output correct value if there no space and `r` is 1, otherwise `b` = 0  and `r` is -1 (EOF).

Give it a try!!

---

**EDIT:**  There is chance of e buffer overrun but can be corrected using dynamic allocation.

Comment: Careful, you have a redundant `s` after the `]` in the first sscanf

Comment: @DimaRudnik  : yes, you are right, corrected , Although that was working!--Thanks Dima R.

Comment: Note that this code can generate buffer overrun if "N_234" is user input, and user gives lengthy string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int r;
unsigned b;
char c[20];
r = sscanf("N_ 234", "N_%[0-9]", c); /* Returns 0 */
r = sscanf("N_-234", "N_%[0-9]", c); /* Returns 0 */
r = sscanf("N_1234", "N_%[0-9]", c); /* Returns 1 */
b = atoi(c);
```

Comment: Thanks Grijesh! You complete me. :P

Comment: welmoce dear +1 to you too ;).